# jQuery Plugin Remove Element From Each Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove and element from an each() loop inside a plugin so I will only return some specific itens. But so far I made many tests and I still cannot remove the item.

```
(function($){

$.fn.teste = function(parametro){

    var parametro_padrao = {};
    if (parametro){$.extend(parametro_padrao, parametro);}

    return this.each(function(){

        //if certain condition happens I want to remove an element  so it will not be returned in the "return" clause above

    });


};

})(jQuery);
```

EDIT:

the :hidden or :visible are not good cause they use offset which I believe is a bad idea.

After some time I found a great solution and I will share so others will not lose time as me:

```
(function($){

$.fn.visivel = function(parametro){

    var parametro_padrao = {};
    if (parametro){$.extend(parametro_padrao, parametro);}

    elemento = this;
    this.each(

        function(index){

            $(this).parents().andSelf().each(

                function() {

                    if (   ($(this).css("display") == "none")   ||   ($(this).css("visibility") == "hidden")   ) {

                        delete elemento[index];
                        return false;

                    }

                }

            );      

        }

    );

    return elemento;

};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use filter():

```
return this.filter(function(){
         return mycondition?true:false;
    });
```

Comment: You are great but I reallly need to remove the specific item using a complex algorythm and using a plugin. I made a few changes in the code but will have problems: $.fn.teste = function(parametro){
 
  var parametro_padrao = {};
  if (parametro){$.extend(parametro_padrao, parametro);}
  
  temp = this;
  this.each(function(index){
  
   $(this).parents().andSelf().each(
   
    function() {
    
     if (   ($(this).css("display") == "none")   ||   ($(this).css("visibility") == "hidden")   ) {
     
      temp.splice(index,1);
      //return false;
     
     }
    
    }
    
   );  
 
  });

Comment: what you are looking for is exactly for what .filter() is used: http://api.jquery.com/filter/  BTW you should use if($(this).is(':hidden'))

Comment: `mycondition` can be any complex expression or a call to a function.

Comment: You don't need the ternary, just `return mycondition`.